# Reference about Karen Uhlenbeck

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

When I read Hamilton's 'FOUR-MANIFOLDS WITH POSITIVE CURVATURE OPERATOR',I am curious the details about  Karen Uhlenbeck trick. But I can't find suitable reference to read it . What should I read about this trick ?

> [image]

Comment: This kind of comment very often means something like 'personal communication'. Otherwise you'd very likely see a reference here. The text, in addition, indicates that the details about the trick are written down to the extent necessary  (in the eyes of the author. That may not be adequate for the average reader..)

Comment: Yes, it sounds like he's (beginning to) describe the trick here.

Comment: If you look up Uhlenbeck trick in Topping's notes on Ricci flow, he explains it in more detail, the notation is different but it's the same thing.

Comment: @Tom  Do you mean the book Lectures on the Ricci flow ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "[The Ricci Flow in Riemannian Geometry](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-16286-2)" by Andrews and Hopper, it is also called Unlenbeck's trick, see chapter 6 in that book.

Comment: Maybe,  I use a different version. It is chapter 5. But still thanks.