# Motivation of Uhlenbeck’s trick without local computation(Suitable connection defined in space time manifold M $\times \mathbb{R}$)

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, ricci-flow

I am a beginner to learn Ricci flow and my main study reference is Simon Brendle’s “Ricci Flow and the Sphere Theorem”. In section 2.3 of Brendle, he introduce the following: let D be the Levi-Civita connection of $TM$ where $M$ is a Riemannian manifold and we define a new connection on $TM \times \mathbb{R}$ via
\begin{equation} 
D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}X = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}X- \sum_{k=1}^n \text{Ric}(X,e_k)e_k \quad(*)
\end{equation}
which is known as Uhlenbeck’s trick. Here $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^n$ is orthonormal frames of $TM$.

I just want to ask the motivation of (*). There are already similar questions: [Linear connection other than Levi-Civita connection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877728/can-linear-connections-other-than-levi-civita-connections-be-useful/1877968#1877968) and [Reference of Uhlenbeck’s trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715649/reference-about-karen-uhlenbeck), but neither of them can solve my question. Since Brendle prefers to do computation in tensor and avoid working in local coordinate, I am glad to hear some motivations of $(*)$ without using local computation.

Followed the advice of the second hyperlink above, I refer to Andrews and Hopper’s book [The Ricci Flow in Riemannian Geometry](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/%7Eandrews/book.pdf). They discussed in lengthy that how to choose a suitable connection on space time manifold $M \times \mathbb{R}$ but I just couldn’t relate to $(*)$ directly.

The following are my attempts: the new connection should satisfy compatibility with Riemannian metric, thus

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g(X,e_l)= g(D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}X, e_l)+0
$$
since $e_l$ is time-independent vector field.
On the other hand, if we compute directly
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} g(X,e_l) = -2 \text{Ric}(X,e_l)+ g(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} X, e_l)
$$
Here we use $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} g(X,Y) = -2 \text{Ric}(X,Y)$.
Does this implies
$$
\begin{equation} 
D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}X = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}X- 2\sum_{k=1}^n \text{Ric}(X,e_k)e_k \quad(*)
\end{equation}
$$

IF the above attempts is true, why there is a factor 2 discrepancy with $(*)$? I hope to hear your insights, and any comments are welcome! Thank you in advance.

Comment: The computations doesn’t seem to consider that $e_l$ is an orthonormal frame that changes with time, when the base metric $g(t)$ is evolving as well. In the book where $e_l$ is replaced with $Y$ the equations are indeed balanced.

Answer (score 1):

This is the introduction lines of Peter Topping *Lectures on Ricci flow* (sec 9.4):

> We have arrived at a relatively simple evolution equation for $E$, and hence
> for the curvature. We wish to apply a maximum principle to find curvature
> conditions which are preserved under the Ricci flow. **One remaining obstacle**
> is that it will be important to see $E$ not just as a section of $T^*M\otimes TM$,
> but as a section of the sub-bundle of such sections which are symmetric
> with respect to $g(t)$. (That is, $g(E(X), Y ) = g(E(Y ),X)$ for all vector
> fields $X$ and $Y$.) Unfortunately, this sub-bundle inherits the $t$-dependence
> of $g(t)$, which would cause problems. we use the so-called
> ‘Uhlenbeck trick’ to hide this $t$-dependence.